# BIRT converting HTML text to plain text in scripts

Tags: javascript, html, java-8, birt

I am attempting to convert HTML entities/tags from a database column into plain text to be displayed in a report. The report is dynamic and as such is created using scripting functions in BIRT.

Since there is no layout displayed I am unable to change the type of the label/text to HTML (as far as I am aware). I have tried a few things but nothing has worked properly. Here is what I am attempting to do - any advice or direction would be very appreciated. Please note I cannot include any 3rd party libraries, but can use anything that comes as fairly standard.

```
function decodeHTML(html) {
    var dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    var builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    var doc = builder.newDocument();

    var txt = doc.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html; //does not work (think this is not avaiable in Java)
    return txt.value;
}
```

*Its worth noting - any other ideas not involving Java or DOM are also acceptable. This was just one of my attempts at solving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to escape HTML:

```
function escapeHTML(str){
   return str.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
    return '&#'+ i.charCodeAt(0)+ ';';
  });
}
```

```js
function escapeHTML(str){
   return str.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
    return '&#'+ i.charCodeAt(0)+ ';';
  });
}
var escaped = escapeHTML("<h1>Header</h1>");
console.log(escaped);
document.body.innerHTML = escaped;
```

```html
<body></body>
```

To decode HTML entities, you can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

```
function decodeHTML(str){
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
```

```js
function decodeHTML(str){
      var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
      return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}
var decoded = decodeHTML("&#60;h1&#62;Header&#60;/h1&#62;");
console.log(decoded);
document.body.innerHTML = decoded;
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: Worth noting - opposite direction was my intent. Looking to take escaped HTML and make it plain text. But this gives me something to work from.

Comment: So I was able to find a similar function online that functions in the reverse.
return str.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, dec) {return String.fromCharCode(dec);}); --- However it goves me an error when running in BIRT: Cannot convert /&#(\d+);/g to java.lang.Character